# How to efficiently find a string that is contained in another string from a different group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

given the following table sample:

| identifier | matched_string |
| --- | --- |
| occupation | manager |
| occupation | manager |
| skill | manager |
| department | marketing manager |
| skill | marketing |

I would like to find the cases where a `matched_string` is contained in another 'matched_string' and have a different identifier.
In the end I would like to get a dataframe that lists these matches.

I have this code so far but I feel it is super inefficient:

```
#df5 is the dataframe I want to search through

df4 = pd.DataFrame()

#find overlaps from matched_strings -> where matched string is contained in another matched string and has a different identifier
for index, row in df5.iterrows():
    for index2, row2 in df5.iterrows():
        if row["matched_string"] in row2["matched_string"] and row["identifier"] != row2["identifier"]:
            df4 = df4.append(row1)
            df4 = df4.append(row2)
```

Would someone have an idea on how to make this more efficient?

Comment: is it possible to include your desired outcome in your question?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't an aggregation as `set` per `matched_string` work for you?

```
df.groupby('matched_string')['identifier'].agg(set)
```

Output:

```
matched_string
manager              {occupation, skill}
marketing                        {skill}
marketing manager           {department}
Name: identifier, dtype: object
```

If you want to use it to filter your DataFrame and keep only the rows with multiple identifiers per matched_string:

```
s = df.groupby('matched_string')['identifier'].agg(set)

idx = s[s.str.len().gt(1)].index

out = df.loc[df['matched_string'].isin(idx)]
```

Output:

```
   identifier matched_string
0  occupation        manager
1  occupation        manager
2       skill        manager
```

Comment: Yes thank you, that was what I was looking for! Do you have an idea how I then could sort the dicts alphabetically and count what is the most frequent combinations of the identifiers? For eg `dups = df.groupby('matched_string')['identifier'].agg(set)` and then `dups[dups.apply(lambda x: len(x)>1)]`. I am looking for something like `value_counts()` for the dicts.